# Need info on using Maven in a integration setting rather than development

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, integration

I am looking for information on using Maven in a integration setting rather than in a development environment.   I see millions of great examples on the internet of using Maven in a development project but finding information or examples of someone using Maven to setup a integration environment, in production, (such as the classpath for an app, property files for an app, directory cleanup for an app, etc.) is what I am trying to find.

Any and all suggestions of sites/links to information in this format would greatly be appreciated.  I will pay it forward.

*Right now I use batch files in a fashion that is similar to how the Tomcat project uses batch files to run the Tomcat server.   So, a use case of the kind of thing I am trying to do, would be to create Maven script that could replace the Tomcat DOS batch file scripts.  Also, this makes me wonder (concerning my example use case I mention here) that if Maven were the way to go, why hasn't Tomcat project done it that way?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to build deliverable packages that include dependencies, config etc.

You can also look in to the [maven-appassembler-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) for generating run scripts (for various platforms) that create correct classpath and then invoke your applications main class.